# Which of these is better and faster?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Regarding performance, which of these is the "best" and the fastest?

Is there a situation where we should not use any of them or even use only one of them? After all, everyone plays the same role.

- RecordInsertList
- insert_recordset
- UnitOfWork

**RecordInsertList**

```
RecordInsertList insertList = new RecordInsertList(tableNum(TableExample));
// some business logic...

insertList.add(buffer1);
insertList.add(buffer2);
insertList.add(buffer3);

insertList.insertDataBase();
```

**insert_recordset**

```
insert_recordset buffer (myNum, mySum)
select myNum, sum(myValue) from otherBuffer
    group by myNum 
    where otherBuffer.myNum == 100;
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

// some business logic...
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer1);
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer2);
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer3);
uow.saveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

`insert_recordset` is faster (but also more limited in functionality) than `RecordInsertList` (see [Optimizing Record Inserts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/optimizing-record-inserts)). `UnitOfWork` is more about data integrity than performance (see [How To: Use the UnitOfWork Class to Manage Database Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-use-the-unitofwork-class-to-manage-database-transactions)). I have no information how its performance compares. [AX 2012 UnitOfWork Performance Series Part 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saviofigueiredo/2014/01/28/ax-2012-unitofwork-performance-series-part-5/) seems to have covered this, but is no longer available. I imagine a quick test job similar to what [AX Performance Insert vs RecordInsertList](https://ztirom.at/2018/11/ax-performance-insert-vs-recordinsertlist/) describes should give some hints.

That covers "fastest". "Best" is a whole other question and without further information on your situation, I cannot answer it objectively.

Personally, I go with `insert_recordset` when possible and `RecordInsertList` if not. I never had a reason to use `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: I thought the same about `insert_recordset` (more limited). I'll try to reproduce the tests you mentioned. Thankful!